# Can "has been" be used in other than "continuous" forms of verbs? Below are sample sentences

Tags: tense, verbs

**1)** He has been doing it for five years - Present Perfect Continuous, **doing** is the **transitive** verb
**2)** He has been quiet for five years - Which form of tense? **Quiet** is an adjective(or past participle maybe) here, **Be** is the **intransitive** verb I suppose because subject **He** receives the action.
**3)** He has been gone for 3 years- Present perfect? As it doesn't look like a continuous action.
I'm confused as to what's happening in 2nd sentence. Does in-transitivity of verbs affect it's form of tense? I'm not sure if I'm phrasing my question correctly :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 1) is a transitive verb, and it is used in the **present** (has) **perfect** (been) **continuous** (doing).

However, the verb being transitive or not (to answer your last question first) has nothing to to with the verb tense, it only refers to whether the verb takes a direct object or not, In 1), the verb *do* takes the direct object *it*.

2) and 3) are the same tense. What may be confusing is the use of *gone*, the pas participle of going, in 3), where it is used as an adjective, just like *quiet* in 2).

The sentences are both **present** (has) **perfect** (been).

You are correct in stating that in 2) and 3) the main verb is *be* and it is intransitive. However, again, that has nothing at all to do with the verb tense. Any verb tense that can be formed with a transitive verb can be formed with an intransitive verb as well.

Comment: How do **He has gone** and **He has been gone** differ grammatically? My idea- **gone** in 1st sentence acts as a **verb** and in **second sentence**, it acts like an **adjective**. Is this so?

Comment: Correct. The main verb in the first is _go_, in the second _be_.